# Edit text cursor selection displays typed character ahead of selection cursor on setting LeadingMarginSpan?

Tags: android, android-edittext, spannablestring

I am trying to set LeadingMarginSpan on part of editText every thing works fine except the way cursor behaves . here's an illustration of what happens :

[image]

when it's reaches the end of the screen then the pink colored selection cursor moves back and what i type appears 3 to 4 charachters after the selection cursor. I tried a lot but was unable to fix it .

How do i make it normal ?

my code:

```java
editorEditText.getText().setSpan(new LeadingMarginSpan.Standard(convertDpToPx(30)),0, editorEditText.getText().length(),
                                        Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

It would be great if any one can help me fix it .

Answer (score 0):

I just fix it.

The problem is that you should update span position after every text input.

You should add a TextWatcher use EditText.addTextChangedListener and in afterTextChanged use code

```
editorEditText.getText().setSpan(new LeadingMarginSpan.Standard(convertDpToPx(30)),0, editorEditText.getText().length(),
                                    Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```